# Insert more records at once in raw_id_fields

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a m2m relation where in my AdminForm I would use raw_id_fields instead of the filter_horizontal option. For explanation I prefer the raw_id_fields instead of the filter_horizontal option, because the records are already categorized. So in the popup-window the user has the ability to search and filter via category. 
But there are two points that I can't figure out:

- possibility to selecting more than one record in the popup window
- showing the real names instead of the pk in the input_field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I'm using a modified https://django-salmonella.readthedocs.org/en/latest/. I don't show the input field and show the selected records in a table.

Comment: I use django-salmonella to `display of an object's string value on change`, how can use it to select multiple records at once?

Answer (score 0):

1. It's possible. In order to select more than one record, you need to override default `dismissRelatedLookupPopup()` in `django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js` by including your script in the `Media` class of your `ModelAdmin` or widget:

   ```
   var dismissRelatedLookupPopup = (function(prev, $) {
       return function(win, chosenId) {
           var name = windowname_to_id(win.name);
           var elem = document.getElementById(name);

           // 1. you could add extra condition checking here, for example
           if ($(elem).hasClass('my_raw_id_ext_cls')) { // add this class to the field
           //     ...logic of inserting picked items from the popup page
           } 
           else { // default logic
               prev(win, chosenId);
           }

           // 2. or you could copy the following part from RelatedObjectLookups.js ...
           if (elem.className.indexOf('vManyToManyRawIdAdminField') != -1 && elem.value) {    
               elem.value += ',' + chosenId;
               // 2. and add a return. Remember this acts globally.
               return;
           } else {
               document.getElementById(name).value = chosenId;
           }

           // 3. the following line cause the popup to be closed while one item is picked. 
           // You could comment it out, but this would also affect the behavior of picking FK items.
           win.close(); 

       }
   })(dismissRelatedLookupPopup, django.jQuery);
   ```
2. Django does not support this by default. There are some snippets at [djangosnippets.org](http://djangosnippets.org/tags/raw_id_fields/), you may want to take a look at them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. These days I will test your hints.

Comment: I started now to implement your inputs. Right now I'm trying to add the standard popup-window (possibility to select only one recod) to the filter_horizontal widget. So actually RelatedObjectLookups.js is still unchanged. The popup opens correctly but when I select a record the window doesn't close, instead switch to the change_form of the selected record. I compared the sourcecode of this popup window with one generated by the raw_id_fields widget and they are identically. @okm I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.